# How do i write on the same textfield from two different methods?

Tags: java, textfield

I created a frame in java with JFrame and then I added a panel (JPanel) in which I want to create a text field to write stuff.
The problem is that I need to write stuff there from different methods.
how can I do that? If I create a TextField I can't modify it from a method that is not the one in which I created it, or not?
I'm a beginner so pls don't tell me to do very complicated things.
I hope I've been clear

```
public class Principale {
JLabel label = new JLabel("test");

        private static JFrame createFrame(){

        JFrame sos0 = new JFrame();
        sos0.setVisible(true);
        sos0.setSize(500, 400);
        sos0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        sos0.setTitle("This is a frame");
        sos0.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        sos0.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );

        sos0.add(label);

        return sos0;

    } // end of method createFrame
```

if I do that I get an error because the object label can't be referenced from a static contest

Comment: You can use the TextField object from both method to setText. If its not accessed by both methods, you need to put it in global scope. Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: Please give us your code so we can help you

Comment: yes you're right I did the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be the fact that create frame just creates a new frame every time, you might be better off making a method that returns void to create the the frame. Personally, I would declare the JLabel as null and the initialise it inside the create method. You could also print out the frame and it's contents to console to see if the variable has any problems.

**Correction:** After putting your code into an IDE it notifies me of the error. Your label variable needs to be static to be accessed from a static method.
E.g. `static JLabel label = new JLabel("test");`

Here is An Example OF Your Solution:

```
private static JLabel label;

private static void createFrame(){

    JFrame sos0 = new JFrame();
    sos0.setVisible(true);
    sos0.setSize(500, 400);
    sos0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    sos0.setTitle("This is a frame");
    sos0.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    sos0.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    label = new JLabel("test");
    sos0.add(label);

}
```

Comment: I edited the original question and I put an example of the problem that occurs. could you give it a read?

Comment: @yZemp , I have updated my response

Comment: ok now I can figure it out thanks